# Spring Integration configure existing flow

Tags: spring-integration

If we have something like this:

```
private void createFlow(String pathOfEndpoint) {

        IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = IntegrationFlows
                                                    .from(confGateway(pathOfEndpoint))
                                                    .<Map<String,String>>handle((p, h) -> {
                                                        return doSomething(p);
                                                    })
                                                    .get();

        getIntegrationFlowContext().registration(integrationFlow).id(pathOfEndpoint).register();
    }
```

And confGateway is:

```
HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway gateway = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(true);
...
return gateway;
```

So we created flow and did registration. My question is, is there a way to configure that flow more in runtime, like after some time to add another `.handle((p,h) -> ....` or if needed to add `.transform(...)`. I tried with `integrationFlow.configure(....)` but I saw that method in StandardIntegrationFlow is this:

```
@Override
    public void configure(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> flow) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

Is it possible to add another `.handle(...)` or similar later somehow? If not, is there other way that i can manipulate with existing flow? maybe subFlow?
I would like to thank Artem Bilan for great support and examples for Spring integration. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why would one create an `IntegrationFlow` at runtime and then decided to modify it later... However it doesn't matter. You need to understand for yourself that `IntegrationFlow` is just a logical configuration component. It doesn't do anything at runtime, during messages processing. What I want to say that at runtime we have a bunch of active components which know nothing about an `IntegrationFlow` created them. They are already tied with each other using EIP principles - channels, endpoints, pollers etc.

Of course those components are flexible and can be adjusted at runtime, but definitely not an `IntegrationFlow` created them. What I mean that you can *subscribe* and *unsubscribe* into/from channels at runtime using their contract. Or you can add (end remove - `stop()` it) a polling endpoint into an existing `QueueChannel`. All other components won't be affected. A *loosely-coupling principle* is one of the main point of the EIP solution.

So, what you asking about dynamic `.handle()` or `.transform()` is more about subscribing new consumers to existing channels. Since it is pretty hard to do that by yourself (you need to have slightly deep knowledge in Spring foundations), you still can use the mentioned `IntegrationFlowContext.registration())`. What you need to have is a channel name from your original flow in its end and use that channel (or its name) to build a new `IntegrationFlow` with required `.handle()` or `.transform()` logic:

```
IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = 
                    IntegrationFlows
                             .from(confGateway(pathOfEndpoint))
                             .<Map<String,String>>handle((p, h) -> {
                                            return doSomething(p);
                             })
                             .channel("mainChannel")
                             .get();

 ... 

 IntegrationFlow otherFlow = 
                    IntegrationFlows
                             .from("mainChannel")
                             .transform(...)
                             .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

No; you can't modify a flow at runtime; you can, however, use [dynamic and runtime integration flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows) and remove a flow and replace it with a new one.

Comment: Yea, I'm using that for flow creation. ty

Comment: See also my answer.